# Shom image on hover over imageurl inside Kendo UI grid cell

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to display in some pop up or tooltip image when user make mouse over url that is displayed inside table cell.

I have made it for now like this and this display image inside cell:

```
{
    field: 'image',
    title: 'Image',
    lockable: false,
    template: 
        '<div class="tooltipcontent">' +
            '<img src="' + '#= image #' + '" alt="" />' +
        '</div>',
    width: '300px'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
        <img style="width:100px" src="#=url#">
    </script>
</div>

$("#grid").kendoGrid({...});

$("#grid").kendoTooltip({
    filter: "td:nth-child(1)", //this filter selects the first column's cells
    position: "right",
    content: function(e) {
        var dataItem = $("#grid").getKendoGrid().dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));
        return kendo.template($("#template").html())(dataItem);
    }
}).data("kendoTooltip");
```

Example: [Row template tooltip](https://dojo.telerik.com/oluNICAj)